# Error when submitting the gcloud task to google cloud ML engine

Tags: keras, google-cloud-platform, python-3.5, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I am new to the Google ML Cloud engine. I would like to post the Keras model to the cloud to train, but I always get this error:

```
I  master-replica-0 Running module trainer.bot.  master-replica-0
I  master-replica-0 Downloading the package: gs://zadravecm-bot/jobs/test_job4/packages/84f3c60920e885020405e1eb7afa5f509313d2a5406a1f1551a81b81993ac66c/trainer-1.0.tar.gz  master-replica-0
I  master-replica-0 Running command: gsutil -q cp gs://zadravecm-bot/jobs/test_job4/packages/84f3c60920e885020405e1eb7afa5f509313d2a5406a1f1551a81b81993ac66c/trainer-1.0.tar.gz trainer-1.0.tar.gz  master-replica-0
I  master-replica-0 Installing the package: gs://zadravecm-bot/jobs/test_job4/packages/84f3c60920e885020405e1eb7afa5f509313d2a5406a1f1551a81b81993ac66c/trainer-1.0.tar.gz  master-replica-0
I  master-replica-0 Running command: pip3 install --user --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-deps trainer-1.0.tar.gz  master-replica-0
I  master-replica-0 Processing ./trainer-1.0.tar.gz  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0 Exception:  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0 Traceback (most recent call last):  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 228, in main  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     status = self.run(options, args)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 291, in run  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     resolver.resolve(requirement_set)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 103, in resolve  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 257, in _resolve_one  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 210, in _get_abstract_dist_for  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     self.require_hashes  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 310, in prepare_linked_requirement  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     progress_bar=self.progress_bar  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 824, in unpack_url  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir, hashes=hashes)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 729, in unpack_file_url  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 578, in unpack_file  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     tarfile.is_tarfile(filename) or  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tarfile.py", line 2448, in is_tarfile  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     t = open(name)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tarfile.py", line 1557, in open  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     return func(name, "r", fileobj, **kwargs)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tarfile.py", line 1629, in gzopen  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     t = cls.taropen(name, mode, fileobj, **kwargs)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tarfile.py", line 1605, in taropen  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     return cls(name, mode, fileobj, **kwargs)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tarfile.py", line 1470, in __init__  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     self.firstmember = self.next()  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tarfile.py", line 2279, in next  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     tarinfo = self.tarinfo.fromtarfile(self)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tarfile.py", line 1082, in fromtarfile  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     buf = tarfile.fileobj.read(BLOCKSIZE)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/gzip.py", line 274, in read  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     return self._buffer.read(size)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_compression.py", line 68, in readinto  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     data = self.read(len(byte_view))  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/gzip.py", line 469, in read  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     uncompress = self._decompressor.decompress(buf, size)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0 zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0 You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0 You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.  master-replica-0
W  master-replica-0 Installation of package failed on try 1/2: Command '['pip3', 'install', '--user', '--upgrade', '--force-reinstall', '--no-deps', 'trainer-1.0.tar.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 2
Retrying ...  master-replica-0
I  master-replica-0 Running command: pip3 install --user --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-deps trainer-1.0.tar.gz  master-replica-0
I  master-replica-0 Processing ./trainer-1.0.tar.gz  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0 Exception:  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0 Traceback (most recent call last):  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 228, in main  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     status = self.run(options, args)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 291, in run  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     resolver.resolve(requirement_set)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 103, in resolve  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 257, in _resolve_one  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 210, in _get_abstract_dist_for  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     self.require_hashes  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 310, in prepare_linked_requirement  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     progress_bar=self.progress_bar  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 824, in unpack_url  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir, hashes=hashes)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 729, in unpack_file_url  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 578, in unpack_file  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     tarfile.is_tarfile(filename) or  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tarfile.py", line 2448, in is_tarfile  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     t = open(name)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tarfile.py", line 1557, in open  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     return func(name, "r", fileobj, **kwargs)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tarfile.py", line 1629, in gzopen  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     t = cls.taropen(name, mode, fileobj, **kwargs)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tarfile.py", line 1605, in taropen  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     return cls(name, mode, fileobj, **kwargs)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tarfile.py", line 1470, in __init__  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     self.firstmember = self.next()  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tarfile.py", line 2279, in next  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     tarinfo = self.tarinfo.fromtarfile(self)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tarfile.py", line 1082, in fromtarfile  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     buf = tarfile.fileobj.read(BLOCKSIZE)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/gzip.py", line 274, in read  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     return self._buffer.read(size)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_compression.py", line 68, in readinto  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     data = self.read(len(byte_view))  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/gzip.py", line 469, in read  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0     uncompress = self._decompressor.decompress(buf, size)  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0 zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0 You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0 You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.  master-replica-0
E  master-replica-0 Command '['pip3', 'install', '--user', '--upgrade', '--force-reinstall', '--no-deps', 'trainer-1.0.tar.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 
2  master-replica-0
I  master-replica-0 Module completed; cleaning up.  master-replica-0
I  master-replica-0 Clean up finished.  master-replica-0
E  The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 2. 
I  Job failed.
```

My terminal script is:

```
export JOB_NAME="test_job4"
export BUCKET_NAME="zadravecm-bot"
export CLOUD_CONFIG=trainer/cloudml-gpu.yaml
export JOB_DIR=gs://zadravecm-bot/jobs/$JOB_NAME
export MODULE=trainer.bot
export PACKAGE_PATH=./trainer
export REGION=us-central1
export RUNTIME=1.8

gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
    --job-dir $JOB_DIR \
    --runtime-version $RUNTIME \
    --module-name $MODULE \
    --package-path $PACKAGE_PATH \
    --region $REGION \
    --config $CLOUD_CONFIG
```

and the GPU configurations

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: BASIC_GPU
  runtimeVersion: "1.8"
  pythonVersion: "3.5"
```

my application hierarchy is:

```
Bot
|
|---> trainer
    |
    | ---> __init__.py
    | ---> bot.py
    | ---> cloudml-gpu.yaml
|
|---> setup.py
```

Comment: By seeing stacktrace, have you tried to run `pip install --upgrade pip` and execute again?

Comment: No, and I don't know how to do that with gcloud...

Comment: My first thought was to run `pip install --upgrade pip` in the Cloud Shell since the error seems to be related to `trainer-1.0.tar.gz` installation and `pip` version. I'm not sure if the local change will affect submitted jobs or not but you can try it to see if it solves the issue or not. From the other side, you may have a look into Stackdriver Logging (if activated) or local logs to search related information about the error.

Comment: @MarkoZadravec. This is indeed strange. Can you send your project and job id(s) to cloudml-feedback@google.com so we can investigate?