# Package fails to install after successful job submission on google ml-engine

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I want to run a job in Google ml-engine. I verified the package worked correctly locally first and followed the tutorial [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-machine-learning-models-in-the-cloud-using-cloud-ml-engine-3f0d935294b3) to submit it to the cloud. The job is submitted successfully but then I get: 

`error: Error -3 while decompressing: invalid distance too far back`

---

I saw that there was a question on a similar error [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51609174/error-when-submitting-the-gcloud-task-to-google-cloud-ml-engine) but it hasn't been fixed. 

I also saw that this type of error was usually fixed by upgrading pip and setuptools, however my local versions are all up to date and I don't see a way to update those tools in the cloud myself.

For now I am trying to run a simple demo job where I enter a name and print it out in the console.

---

Platform: Windows 10 
Python: 2.7 
Command line arguments:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training hello_world \
                 --package-path=mypackage/trainer \
                 --module-name=trainer.demo --region=europe-west1 \ 
                 --staging-bucket=gs://bucket_name \
                 --scale-tier=BASIC \ 
                 -- \ 
                 --name=Bob
```

My file structure is:

```
mypackage\
     |_____ trainer\
                |_____ __init__.py
                |_____ demo.py
     |_____ setup.py
```

My setup.py file is:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

# Setup parameters for Google Cloud ML Engine
setup(name='trainer',
      version='0.1',
      packages=find_packages(),
      description='Example to run a script on gcloud ml-engine',
      install_requires=['keras',
                        'h5py'],
      zip_safe=False)
```

---

Another confusing aspect is that the same exact job did work at times. Then I want to try out something new and get a decompression error but when I revert back to the former working code, I still get the same decompression error.

Here is the traceback of this error:

> INFO    2019-01-15 11:05:48 +0100       service         Validating job requirements... 
>   INFO    2019-01-15 11:05:49 +0100       service         Job creation request has been successfully validated. 
>   INFO    2019-01-15 11:05:49 +0100       service         Job hello_world is queued. 
>   INFO    2019-01-15 11:05:49 +0100       service         Waiting for job to be provisioned. 
>   INFO    2019-01-15 11:05:53 +0100       service         Waiting for training program to start. 
>   INFO    2019-01-15 11:06:41 +0100       master-replica-0                Running task with arguments: --cluster={"master": ["127.0.0.1:2222"]} --task={"type": "master", "index": 0} --job={  "package_uris": ["gs://bucket_name/hello_world/0e742936e56a23c9f32a5c1a0bf40692436447395149b8b00def4f2fb2efccd9/trainer-0.1.tar.gz"],  "python_module": "trainer.demo",  "args": ["--name\u003dBob"],  "region": "europe-west1",  "run_on_raw_vm": true} 
>   INFO    2019-01-15 11:06:48 +0100       master-replica-0                Running module trainer.demo. 
>   INFO    2019-01-15 11:06:48 +0100       master-replica-0                Downloading the package:  gs://bucket_name/hello_world/0e742936e56a23c9f32a5c1a0bf40692436447395149b8b00def4f2fb2efccd9/trainer-0.1.tar.gz 
>   INFO    2019-01-15 11:06:48 +0100       master-replica-0                Running command: gsutil -q cp gs://bucket_name/hello_world/0e742936e56a23c9f32a5c1a0bf40692436447395149b8b00def4f2fb2efccd9/trainer-0.1.tar.gz trainer-0.1.tar.gz 
>   INFO    2019-01-15 11:06:50 +0100       master-replica-0                Installing the package: gs://bucket_name/hello_world/0e742936e56a23c9f32a5c1a0bf40692436447395149b8b00def4f2fb2efccd9/trainer-0.1.tar.gz 
>   INFO    2019-01-15 11:06:50 +0100       master-replica-0                Running command: pip install --user --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-deps trainer-0.1.tar.gz 
>   INFO    2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                Processing ./trainer-0.1.tar.gz 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0    
>             Exception: 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0    
>             Traceback (most recent call last):
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 143, in main 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                    status = self.run(options, args) 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 318, in run 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                    resolver.resolve(requirement_set) 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 102, in resolve 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req) 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install) 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 209, in _get_abstract_dist_for 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                    self.require_hashes 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 283, in prepare_linked_requirement  
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                    progress_bar=self.progress_bar 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/download.py", line 823, in unpack_url 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                    unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir, hashes=hashes) 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/download.py", line 728, in unpack_file_url 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                    unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link) 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 585, in unpack_file 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                    tarfile.is_tarfile(filename) or 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2608, in is_tarfile 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                    t = open(name) 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1666, in open 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                    return func(name, "r", fileobj, **kwargs) 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1738, in gzopen 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                    t = cls.taropen(name, mode, fileobj, **kwargs) 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1714, in taropen 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                    return cls(name, mode, fileobj, **kwargs) 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1580, in **init** 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                    self.firstmember = self.next() 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2342, in next 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                    tarinfo = self.tarinfo.fromtarfile(self) 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1244, in fromtarfile 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                    buf = tarfile.fileobj.read(BLOCKSIZE) 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 268, in read 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                    self._read(readsize) 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 319, in _read 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0                    uncompress = self.decompress.decompress(buf) 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0  
>                error: Error -3 while decompressing: invalid distance too far back 
>   WARNING 2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100   
>   master-replica-0                Installation of package failed on try 1/2: 
>  Command '['pip', 'install', '--user', '--upgrade', '--force-reinstall', '--no-deps', u'trainer-0.1.tar.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 2 
>   WARNING 2019-01-15 11:07:03 +0100       master-replica-0      
>           Retrying ... 
>   [...] 
>   INFO    2019-01-15 11:07:04 +0100       master-replica-0                Module completed; cleaning up. 
>   INFO    2019-01-15 11:07:04 +0100       master-replica-0                Clean up finished. 
>   ERROR   2019-01-15 11:07:05 +0100       service         The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 2.

Comment: I would suggest trying `--runtime-version=1.12`; the default is 1.0 which is quite old and has older dependencies.  I can't guarantee this will work, but can you try it to see if it still causes problems?

Comment: @rhaertel80 thanks for the suggestion. It works with this hello_world but when I sent another model (also verified locally) I now get a `error: Error -3 while decompressing: invalid literal/lengths set`. 

I then tried to re-run the hello_world model with the exact same parameters and got a `ReadError: not a gzip file`. Do you have any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: That is all very strange. Please send email to cloudml-feedback@google.com and provide your project number and any applicable job ids (along with a link to this post).